Pandas dense rank with same values in order by
I have the following DataFrame in Pandas:



ID
snapshot_date
row_hash




qwe
Jan 01 2024
123


qwe
Jan 03 2024
456


qwe
Jan 05 2024
456


qwe
Jan 07 2024
123



Note: that row_hash changed back on Jan 07 2024
I want to create 3 groups (like window function in SQL), but I can't get the desired rseult:



ID
snapshot_date
row_hash
dense_rank I get
dense_rank needed




qwe
Jan 01 2024
123
1
1


qwe
Jan 03 2024
456
1
2


qwe
Jan 05 2024
456
2
2


qwe
Jan 07 2024
123
2
3



I tried to create it with the code:
snapshot_df['dense_rank'] = snapshot_df.groupby(['ID', 'row_hash'])['snapshot_date'].rank(
            method='dense').astype(int)

Can anybody help me?

If need counter for change by columns ID and row_hash compare by shifted values by DataFrame.shift with DataFrame.any and Series.cumsum:
cols = ['ID', 'row_hash']
df['dense_rank'] = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
print (df)
    ID snapshot_date  row_hash  dense_rank
0  qwe   Jan 01 2024       123           1
1  qwe   Jan 03 2024       456           2
2  qwe   Jan 05 2024       456           2
3  qwe   Jan 07 2024       123           3

How it working:
print (df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()))
      ID  row_hash
0   True      True
1  False      True
2  False     False
3  False      True

print (df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print (df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
dtype: int32

EDIT: Solution for groups:
cols = ['ID', 'row_hash']
df['dense_rank'] = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()

Or:
cols = ['ID', 'row_hash']
df['dense_rank'] = (df.assign(g = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1))
                      .groupby(['ID'])['g']
                      .cumsum())


print (df)
      ID snapshot_date  row_hash  dense_rank
0   qwe   Jan 01 2024        123           1
1   qwe   Jan 03 2024        456           2
2   qwe   Jan 05 2024        456           2
3   qwe   Jan 07 2024        123           3
4  qwe1   Jan 01 2024        123           1
5  qwe1   Jan 03 2024        456           2
6  qwe1   Jan 05 2024        456           2
7  qwe1   Jan 07 2024        123           3


Great solution, thanks! But if add another ID rows (e.g. duplicate rows but with other id). The dense_rank numbers woud continue, is there a way to group it by ID? Thank you in advance
